# How to make a ember app talk to an express api in production with Nqinx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ember.js

Im working in and Ember App that use a API build with Express js, for development i just run my express api and then run `ember server --proxy http://localhost:8000`
 for example i could be whatever port, so now i have to deploy that to a production environment that im working on, i planing to use nginx, but what i do not know and can't fine is that once a build my ember app for PROD and make nginx serve this files, how do i do to make the ember app knows where to talk to the api.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the host property for your application adapter (which you will need to generate): http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#property_host